# Do the Visual Studio git tools require a separate git installation?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Do the visual studio git tools come with their own implementation of git, or do they require a separate installation of git?

Comment: 2013 and higher should have it backed in, see [Get started using Git in Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/get-started)

Answer (score 2):

The Visual Studio Git Tools do *not* require a separate installation of Git.  For Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015, the tools make use of the [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2) and [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) projects and do not actually call `git` at all.

(However the tools *will* suggest you install the latest version of [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io) for you to use on the command-line.)

Answer (score 0):

It does not have a baked in git repository.  You must configure VS to tell it what git repository to use.